# Invalid MailChimp API Key in Mailchimp Export API

Tags: api, export, mailchimp

I have everything ok in the Mailchimp account but still facing the following problem -

Type the URL - http://us1.api.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/list/?apikey=mykey-us6&id=myid

Output -
{"error":"Invalid MailChimp API Key: mykey","code":104}

Answer (score 12):

This error occurs if you don't use the correct URL.

If your API key ends with **"us9"** the URL to be called is "http://**us9**.api.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/list/?apikey=yourkey-us6&id=yourid"

If the URL you have added in the question to work, you should add an API key ending **"us1"**